# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ ic_launcher')

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am completely new to Android and have been trying to launch a maps example from the SDK, however, my google play service library when added to workspace gives error in the manifest.xml file. MainActivity>AndroidManifest.xml
I tried changing the properties to Google API 15 and also edited the xml file but it still doesn't work. Any help would be useful, thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapdemo" android:versionCode="8"
android:versionName="4.0.3">
<!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- End of copy. -->
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" <!--Error: No resource found that matches the     given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher')-->
    android:label="@string/demo_title" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"> <!--Error: No resource     found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/basic_map_demo_label')
-->
    <!-- ** You need to replace the key below with your own key. ** The example 
        key below will not be accepted because it is not linked to the certificate 
        which you will use to sign this application. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start 
        for instructions on how to get your own key. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="i_enter_my_key_here" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LegalInfoActivity" android:label="@string/legal_info" />
    <activity android:name=".BasicMapDemoActivity" android:label="@string/basic_map_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".CameraDemoActivity" android:label="@string/camera_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".CircleDemoActivity" android:label="@string/circle_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".EventsDemoActivity" android:label="@string/events_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".GroundOverlayDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/ground_overlay_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".IndoorDemoActivity" android:label="@string/indoor_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".LayersDemoActivity" android:label="@string/layers_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".LocationSourceDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/location_source_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".MapInPagerDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/map_in_pager_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".MarkerDemoActivity" android:label="@string/marker_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".MultiMapDemoActivity" android:label="@string/multi_map_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".MyLocationDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/my_location_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".OptionsDemoActivity" android:label="@string/options_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".PolygonDemoActivity" android:label="@string/polygon_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".PolylineDemoActivity" android:label="@string/polyline_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".ProgrammaticDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/programmatic_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".RawMapViewDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/raw_map_view_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".RetainMapDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/retain_map_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".SaveStateDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/save_state_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".SnapshotDemoActivity" android:label="@string/snapshot_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".SplitStreetViewPanoramaAndMapDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/split_street_view_panorama_and_map_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".StreetViewPanoramaBasicDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_view_panorama_basic_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".StreetViewPanoramaEventsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_view_panorama_events_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".StreetViewPanoramaNavigationDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_view_panorama_navigation_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".StreetViewPanoramaOptionsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_view_panorama_options_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".StreetViewPanoramaViewDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/street_view_panorama_view_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".TileCoordinate`enter code here`DemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/tile_coordinate_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".TileOverlayDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/tile_overlay_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".UiSettingsDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/ui_settings_demo_label" />
    <activity android:name=".VisibleRegionDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/visible_region_demo_label" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Where is the error exactly, can You post the log?

Comment: I have edited the xml to show the errors at line 18. The same error appears at every label statement in the rest of the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a file called ic_launcher in the res/drawable directory. This is usually a png that follows the requirements at [Android Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). For learning purposes you can just have the ic_launcher in the drawable directory (that you may have to add to your project) with a single icon inside. Later when you get to your actual project you may want different icon sizes as per the specs.

Also make sure you have a string named demo_title in a resource file somewhere. Usually there is a file called, for example "strings.xml" in the res/values directory and inside there is a string declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="demo_title">This is my Demo</string>
</resources>
```